# Generalization of Jensen's inequality to multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is there a generalization of Jensen's inequality for convex multivariate functions? By convex, let's say $f$ is a multivariate function defined on the convex set $A$, and for all $x,y \in A$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, 
$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).$$
Then, letting $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ denote points in $A$, the result would be something to the effect of saying that for any $n$ points in $A$,
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}{n} \geq f \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{n} \right). $$
I do see a few articles that *may* be related:

1. Perlman, Michael D. "Jensen's inequality for a convex vector-valued function on an infinite-dimensional space." Journal of Multivariate Analysis 4.1 (1974): 52-65.
2. Merkle, Milan. "Jensen's inequality for multivariate medians." Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 370.1 (2010): 258-269.
3. Aras-Gazic, G., et al. "GENERALIZATION OF JENSEN’S INEQUALITY BY HERMITE POLYNOMIALS AND RELATED RESULTS." Mathematical reports 17.2 (2015): 201-223.
4. Agnew, Robert A. "Multivariate version of a Jensen-type inequality." J. Inequal. in Pure and Appl. Math 6.4 (2005).

I do not think the first is particularly related if I'm interested in finite dimensional spaces, and my function is not vector-valued in any case. The second may be more related, but it seems to be generalizing in slightly different directions. The third is beyond my comprehension and the fourth, again, seems to be working on a slightly different generalization.

Are there no less technical generalizations of Jensen's to multivariate functions out there?

Comment: @Did I'm not sure I follow. I'm thinking $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $u$ and $v$ (or $x$ and $y$) are vectors, then, but where am I using any notion of their ordering? Or could you perhaps point me someplace to better understand your first sentence?

Comment: Right, then the answer is simple: Jensen holds for every convex function, defined on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^n$ or whatever. Note that, in any dimension, convexity is the property that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leqslant \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$ for every $(x,y)$ and every $\lambda$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Did Would you say then that what I'm speaking of is just the finite form of [the general inequality in a probabilistic setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting)? The Wikipedia proof of this result is a bit incomplete, but there's a note to reference the Feldman paper. So, does the result I'm after really come directly from Jensen's inequality, which I see stated for a single variable, or from somebody's generalization of it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The paper you cite deals with subtleties involved when the underlying space is infinite dimensional. For the classical proof, valid in your setting, rather see [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_2_.28measure-theoretic_form.29).

Comment: From that proof: "$\ldots \varphi$ be a convex function on the real numbers. Since $\varphi$ is convex, at each real number $x \ldots$". Isn't this univariate?

Comment: Yeah, $\phi$ is defined on the space where the image set of $f$ is (well, actually, on at least a part of it). Thus, on $\mathbb R$. Otherwise, we are back at my now deleted first comment.

Comment: My apologies. So the analog of my $f$ is their $g$, which is real-valued but potentially defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Comment: I still don't see the equivalence (for instance, my convexity assumption is on $f$, which is their $g$, but theirs is on $\varphi$), but, assuming you're correct (which I do), I'll probably see it upon reflecting on it a bit longer.

Comment: Just yell if the mystery does not dissolve by itself...

Comment: @Did OK, still feeling somewhat sheepish, I'm yelling. It would still appear to me that the analog of my $f$ is their $\varphi$, not the $g$. The $g$ is just a pdf. And while their $g$ can be defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi$ is just defined on $\mathbb{R}$. A similar proof in Rudin also covers only the univariate case. Help me see the nuance I'm missing...

Comment: Rereading your question and the comments, I must admit being a little lost. Is your goal to show that, if $f$ is a multivariate function defined on some convex set $A$, and if, for all $x$ and $y$ in $A$ and all $\lambda$ in $[0,1]$, 
$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$, then, for all $n$ and all points $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ in $A$, one has $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\geqslant f \left(\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i} \right)$? Because this one has self-contained short proofs, for example, by induction on $n$.

Comment: @Did Yes, that's exactly it. Can you point me to one of those self-contained short proofs with induction on $n$? That's what I had figured would have existed but haven't been able to find.

Comment: To deduce the $n+1$ case of the inequality from the $n$ case, use $\lambda=\frac1{n+1}$, $x=x_{n+1}$, $y=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$, then $z=\frac1{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ hence $f(z)\leqslant\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$, now by the recurrence hypothesis, $f(y)\leqslant\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(x_k)$, hence $f(z)\leqslant\lambda f(x_{n+1})+(1-\lambda)\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(x_k)$, qed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jensen's inequality always holds when you're dealing with a convex function whose domain is finite-dimensional. By restricting the domain of $f$ to $S := \text{span} \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, we put the question into that setting and know that $f(\mathbb{E} X) \leq \mathbb{E} f(X)$ for *any* random vector $X$ taking values in $S$. In particular, it holds when the distribution of $X$ is uniform on $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$.