# Interpretation of Jensen's inequality for the multivariate case

Tags: real-analysis, jensen-inequality

Isn't Jensen's inequality just the definition of a convex function?

$\phi(\sum_{n}\lambda_{i}x_{i}) \leq \sum_{n}\lambda_{i}\phi(x_{i})$

Looking at the wiki page of [Jensens inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) the diagram is just the figure of a convex function (indeed the same figure appears on the page  of [convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)).

What exactly is the difference between the case of $n=2$ and arbitrary $n$ when they both state that the function is convex? Were one to suppose that the case of arbitrary $n$ is for the multidimensional case, there doesn't seem to be a multivariate equivalent of $\phi$ since a multivariate function is expected to look like $\Phi(X_{1}, X_{2}, ... X_{n})$ but the $\phi$ in this case always looks like a univariate $\Phi(X)$, where the $X$ can be $\lambda_{1}x_{1}$ or $\lambda_{1}x_{1} + \lambda_{2}x_{2}$ or $\lambda_{1}x_{1} + \lambda_{1}x_{1} + \cdots + \lambda_{n}x_{n}$ (where $\sum_{n}\lambda_{i} = 1$) : ultimately just a single term.

So, going by that [Wiki figure](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/ConvexFunction.svg) (on the pages linked above), if a function is convex between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, is there a chance adding numerous other points in between (which is basically the statement of the $n$ dimensional case) would change that fact (thus needing a proof)?

I did spend a while looking through this [other closely related math.SE discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848487/generalization-of-jensens-inequality-to-multivariate-functions) but that did not answer any of my questions - the final comment there is just that nice little proof by induction, which I am already perfectly fine with. What I don't understand if the generic case says something non-obvious. Please explain if it does.

Apologies if the question is a bit vague. Even though I can do the proofs by induction, I am myself unclear if it signifies anything significant.

Comment: We use the definition of convex function and induction to prove Jensen's inequality in discrete case.

Comment: Hello !  The Jensen Inequality for the case $n=2$ is exactly the definition for a convex function, that is why it is helpful to use it in the proof by induction.   Although taking more points, doesn't mean (at least that I know), to do a multidimensional equivalence or generalization. You are just taking more points in the domain and study what happens to the "average" when a convex function is evaluated in it. I think is useful to study the concept of epigraph (not for the proof, but to get an idea of what is going on), as well as doing a numerical test, you can try with the function $x^2$

Comment: Multivariate version of Jensen exists, though what’s on the wiki page referred is univariate case, applied to several points in a one dimensional interval. In other words it’s for $f:\mathbb R\mapsto \mathbb R$. A multivariate counterpart would deal with say $s$-dimensional space ie $F:\mathbb R^s\mapsto \mathbb R$, and can still have $n$ points $\in \mathbb R^s$.

Comment: @Macavity yes, exactly; you comprehend my troubles. Would you please clarify if there's a point (unintended pun) to applying it to the case of several points in a 1D interval? Looking at the Wiki figure I linked to, it seems redundant to me. Also, would you be kind enough to share an example of the actual multivariate case with me? I haven't been able to find anything on it either on Wiki, or the Rudin book, or the open (non-paywalled) internet.. Cheers!

Comment: Not sure where you can find a free but comprehensive treatment of multivariate extensions.  Check http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~dstephens/556-2008/Math556-15-MVJensens.pdf which provides a snapshot in a probabilistic setting.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I'll read it through. I believe I might have found something to partly answer my question in [this paper](https://art.torvergata.it/retrieve/handle/2108/37039/11311/convex.pdf) I found. In the intro, he writes, "One of the most interesting results, establishing a liaison between convexity and probability, is the so-called Jensen’s inequality". Indeed it might make some sense to have to prove it for probabilities, though not so much for real analysis.